# Notify app when iPad date time settings changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I would like to get notified when ipad's date-time settings is changed. Is there any way for that?.

I am using NSDateFormatter to find whether iPad/iphone time mode is 12 or 24 hr format. NSDateFormatter is seems to take lots of time( seen in time profiling). So I would like to check use it only when settings is changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it using two ways:

1. **Implement `- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application` in your app delegate.**
2. **Add a observer for `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`**

   **`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChanged:) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];`**

> **applicationSignificantTimeChange:**
>
> Tells the delegate when there is a significant change in the time.
>   `- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application`
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> **application**
>
> ```
> The delegating application object.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight,
>   an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings
>   time. The delegate can implement this method to adjust any object of
>   the application that displays time or is sensitive to time changes.
>
> Prior to calling this method, the application also posts a
>   UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification notification to give
>   interested objects a chance to respond to the change.
>
> If your application is currently suspended, this message is queued
>   until your application returns to the foreground, at which point it is
>   delivered. If multiple time changes occur, only the most recent one is
>   delivered. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIApplication.h

For more check [UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Accepted for the detailed answer. Thanks!!.

Answer (score 7):

How about adding an observer for [NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ? Per Apple, "Re-create any cached date and number formatter objects whenever the current locale information changes."

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to listen to this notification:
[`NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssystemtimezonedidchangenotification)