# Notifying timezone change to an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, timezone, nsnotificationcenter

I would like to get a clarification on notifying the timezone change in an app.

- **Scenario 1**: When the user changes the timezone manually from the iPhone settings. I guess in this case, following post will workout.

[Notify app when iPad date time settings changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741585/notify-app-when-ipad-date-time-settings-changed)

- **Scenario 2**: If the app is in foreground and the user is travelling to a different timezone from the timezone set in phone settings. In this case, is there any way that the app can be notified about the change of timezone? That means when ever the location changes to a different timezone, will it be possible to notify the app about change in timezone.

I have seen one more way the timezone change can be notified, which is given as following.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeZoneChanged) name: NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Can anyone give the best way of notifying the timezone change based on scenario 2.

Comment: You can handle both notifications by letting them call the same method.  All you need to know is that any times that you are displaying may have to change; in the rare case that you would display the user's time zone, that needs changing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle both notifications by letting them call the same method.  All you need to know is that any times that you are displaying may have to change; in the rare case that you would display the user's time zone, that needs changing as well. Both notifications will be rare, so it would be easiest to just redisplay everything.

You might also consider looking at nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition; if there's anything that needs changing. For example if I set an alarm to 8am and you notice that daylight saving time changes between now and the alarm, you could ask if you want the alarm at 8am tomorrow, or 24 hours after 8am, today.

Comment: My requirement is just to get the user's current timezone.